# How to set custom final price on product page or product listing page?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, price

In Magento 1.9, I have used  the  event `catalog_product_get_final_price` to set a custom final price for the product page. However in Magento 2 the price is not changing when using the same event.

Comment: Acknowledged bug in Magento2,
See [issue 4027](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4027)

Comment: It's Magento 2. You can use the plugin system.